# MySQL query - Return consult even if one field doesn't exist in the related tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this Query:

```
 SELECT of2ab_content.id, of2ab_content.title, of2ab_content.metakey, of2ab_content.metadesc, of2ab_content.introtext, of2ab_content.fulltext AS completetext, of2ab_content.publish_up, of2ab_users.name AS author 
 FROM of2ab_content, of2ab_users 
 WHERE of2ab_content.id = 5039
 AND (of2ab_users.id=of2ab_content.created_by)
```

The problem here is when in the field exist in *of2ab_content.created_by* but it does not exist on the table *of2ab_users.id*, then the query return empty. I need the query to return the rest of the fields if the author does not exist in the users table.

Any suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a `left join`.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause; *always* use explicit `join` syntax.

```
SELECT c.id, c.title, c.metakey, c.metadesc, of2ab_content.introtext,
       c.fulltext AS completetext, c.publish_up, u.name AS author 
 FROM of2ab_content c LEFT JOIN
      of2ab_users u
      ON u.id = c.created_by
WHERE c.id = 5039;
```

Note that the use of table aliases always makes the query easier to write and to read.